# How to Relate Engineering Writing of Sifting Property of Dirac $\delta$ to Its Rigorous Form in Tempered Distribution

Tags: signal-processing

The normal writing of sifting property in signal processing is

\begin{equation}
\psi\left(x\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(x - y\right)\psi\left(y\right)\mathrm{d}y,
\end{equation}
where $\delta$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\delta\left(x\right) = 
\begin{cases}
\infty,\ x = 0\\
0,\ \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x = 1.
\end{equation}

Then we have a more rigorous definition for $\delta$ as a distribution (functional) defined on the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}$:
\begin{equation}
\forall \phi \in \mathcal{S}, \langle \delta, \phi \rangle = \phi\left(0\right).
\end{equation}
By defining convolution as an operation $*: \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D}$  ($\mathcal{D}$ to be the space of tempered distributions on $\mathcal{S}$):
\begin{equation}
\langle\psi * T, \phi\rangle = \langle T, \psi^{-} * \phi \rangle ,
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
\psi * \delta = \psi.
\end{equation}
Then my question is, how to relate the above equation which is more rigorous to the one less rigorous typically used in engineering writing?

Comment: Isn't your last equation precisely the same as the first one? Just a different notation. Not sure how much more do you want.

Comment: The Dirac Delta is a distribution on $C_C^\infty$, which is a subset of $S$.